# Error Message: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [[ 2]] of <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to copy rows from one dataframe to another based on the indices stored in an array. While using the following code:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(
   {
        "column_1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "column_2": ['A','B','C','D'],
        "column_3": [3.1, 7.8, 9.0, 5.8]
   }
)
   Arr1=np.array([[2],[3]])

   column_name = ['column_2','column_3'];
   index_row=range(4);
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index_row,columns=column_name);

   for i in range(4):
          df2[i:i+1]=df1[(Arr1[i]):(Arr1[i]+1)]
```

I get the following error: cannot do slice indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex' with these indexers [[2]] of class 'numpy.ndarray'.

Can someone suggest a correct approach?

Comment: First of all you missed the bracket at the end of pd.DataFrame().
Second what is the Variable Arr in the for loop. you mean Arr1?
Please check your code and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the id's properly, transform the array to a list with only the values in it. `i[0]` gets the first (and in this case only one) value from the list [2] and [3].

Then use `.loc[ids,columns]` to choose the rows and columns you want to copy. No need for a loop here.
Thats an easier and faster approach

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    "column_1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "column_2": ['A','B','C','D'],
    "column_3": [3.1, 7.8, 9.0, 5.8]})
Arr1=np.array([[2],[3]])
#------------new-----------------
ids=[i[0] for i in Arr1.tolist()]
#--------------------------------


column_name = ['column_2','column_3']


#------------new-----------------
df2 = df1.loc[ids,column_name]
#--------------------------------
```